# Is there an open-source eMail message (headers, attachments, etc.) parser?

Tags: java, php, python, email, parsing

Is there a free open-source solution taking raw e-mail message (as a piece of text) and returning each header field, each attachment and the message body as separate fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a common task and there are a number of apis out there to help you.

If working with Java, I'd look at [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/).

If working with PHP, I'd look at [PECL mailparse](http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse) or [Pear Mail](http://pear.php.net/Mail/).

Comment: Hmm, judging by that tick, sounds like his real question was: "What is a good email parsing library for Java and PHP?"

Answer (score 2):

Yes... For each language you pointed out, I've used the one in Python myself.  Try perusing the library documentation for your chosen library.

(Note: You may be expecting a "nice", high-level library for this parsing...  That's a tricky area, email has evolved and grown without much design, there are a lot of dark corners, and API's reflect that).

Answer (score 0):

```
javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
    protected void parse(InputStream is)
```